# Counting uniques on a week by week basis

Tags: google-bigquery

I've managed to find the unique # of session_ids within the first week of the the year with this query.

How do I get each successive week's unique count up to the last week of June?

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT session_id),
  MAX(timestamp_local)
FROM
  `myTable`
WHERE
  timestamp >= '2018-01-01'
  AND timestamp <= '2018-01-07'
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Google BigQuery has the function [`EXTRACT()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#extract). You can use it to get the year and week components of a `date`.

For example, for the year component:

```
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) AS year
```

For the week component:

```
EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date) AS week
```

Your `timestamp` values will also need [`cast()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#casting)ing to a `date` datatype so that we can use the above functions  (I'm assuming that they are `timestamp`, given your column name - if not, you can skip the `cast()`).

Seeing as you only want to deal with 2018, you can simply do:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM CAST(timestamp as DATE)) AS week, COUNT (DISTINCT session_id)
FROM
  `myTable`
WHERE
  timestamp >= '2018-01-01'
  AND timestamp <= '2018-01-07'
group by EXTRACT(WEEK FROM CAST(timestamp as DATE));
```

Note: Untested, as I don't have an environment, this answer is based on documentation